# Python - Save contact to address book and print address book

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to revise this syntax to save an input contact to the save.txt file when the user chooses option 1 and print the contents of save.txt when the user chooses option 2.  Please help?  Thank you!

This is Addressbook.py:

```
from contact import Contact

addressBook = []
choice = 0
save = open("save.txt", 'r')
s = save.read()
s = s.split("~")

while len(s)-4 >= 0:
    addressBook.append(Contact(s.pop(0), s.pop(0), s.pop(0), s.pop(0)))

print("Hello I am an addressbook! What do you want to do?\n1.Add contact")
print("2.Print out contacts\n3.Search for and edit a contact\n4.Exit\n")
choice = int(input())
while choice != 4:
    if choice == 1:
        addressBook.append(Contact(input("First name?"), input("Last name?"), input("Phone number?"), input("Email?")))
    elif choice == 2:
        for x in range(len(addressBook)):
            print(addressBook[x].ToString())
    elif choice == 3:
        print("????")
    choice = int(input("What do you want to do?\n1.Add contact\n2.Print out contacts\n3.Search for and edit a contact\n4.Exit\n"))
```

Comment: what does save.txt look like? does save.txt have to be human readable I.E be red outside of your python program?

Comment: ideally, yes.  I've achieved the objective with pickle, but the save.txt file is necessary.  Right now save.txt is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```py
class Contact:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, phone_num, email):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.phone_num = phone_num
        self.email = email

    def __str__(self):
        return "~".join([self.first_name, self.last_name, self.phone_num, self.email])

address_book = []
try:
    with open("save.txt") as save_file:
        for contact in save_file:
            address_book.append(Contact(*contact.rstrip().split("~")))
except FileNotFoundError as fefe:
    pass

print("Hello I am an addressbook! What do you want to do?\n1.Add contact")
print("2.Print out contacts\n3.Search for and edit a contact\n4.Exit\n")
while True:
    choice = int(input("Choice: "))
    if choice == 1:
        address_book.append(Contact(input("First name?"), input("Last name?"), input("Phone number?"), input("Email?")))
    elif choice == 2:
        print(*[contact for contact in address_book], sep="\n")
    elif choice == 3:
        pass
    elif choice == 4:
        with open("save.txt", "w") as save_file:
            for contact in address_book:
                save_file.write(str(contact) + "\n")
            break
```

Comment: Thank you Chris.  I am very new to Python and OOP.  I'm able to enter a contact with option 1, but when choosing option 2, it returns:  "<__main__.Contact object at 0x000002BEA4FB5250>" instead of the contact.  I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Which version of python are you using

Comment: oh wait, your contact class is not the same as mines. I have implemented the `__str__` method so when things like print get the object it will autoformat it as a stirng. However in your code you need to call the `ToString` method of your class like `print(*[contact.ToString() for contact in address_book], sep="\n")`

Comment: I am using version 3

Comment: Yeah the issue is i have written my example with the inbuilt __str__ method. however your class prob doesnt have that. So you need to update the print line in option2 to call the `ToString` method of contact

Comment: Thank you.  This works great, but I'm curious to know why i cannot see the contact entries in the text file.

Comment: Have you pressed 4 to exit? its only when you select option 4 will the entries in the address_book in memory be written out to the file